# Closed form of $\int\limits_0^{2\pi} \prod\limits_{j=1}^n \cos(jx)dx$ and combinatorial link

Tags: integration, combinatorics, trigonometry, products

I have been trying to find a closed form for this integral:
$$I_n = \int\limits_0^{2\pi} \prod_{j=1}^n \cos(jx)dx$$
The first values are: $I_1=I_2=0,I_3=\frac{\pi}{2}, I_4=\frac{\pi}{4}, I_5=I_6=0, I_7=\frac{\pi}{8}, I_8=\frac{7\pi}{64}$

I am not able to see here a clean pattern except that for $n=4k+1,4k+2$ the integral should be zero. If someone could give me a hint I would appreciate it.

**EDIT**

As suggested by Winther in the comments, the problem can be viewed from a combinatorial standpoint. Looking at the complex exponential representation one gets $2^n$ integrals of the form $\int_0^{2\pi}e^{iNx}dx$, which is only nonzero, if $N=0$. The integral evaluates to $\frac{M\pi}{2^{n-1}}$, where $M$ is the number of nonzero integrals.

So one needs to find $M$, which is the number of binary numbers $b$ for which holds that
$$\sum_{k=1}^n (2b_k-1)k = 0$$
where $b_k$ is the k-th digit of $b$.
With this, it is easy to see if for some $b$ it holds, it will also hold for $\overline{b}$ (each digit is inverted).

Comment: Here are the first $30$ terms, in case that helps:  $$\left\{0,0,\frac{\pi }{2},\frac{\pi }{4},0,0,\frac{\pi }{8},\frac{7 \pi
   }{64},0,0,\frac{35 \pi }{512},\frac{31 \pi }{512},0,0,\frac{361 \pi }{8192},\frac{657
   \pi }{16384},0,0,\frac{2055 \pi }{65536},\frac{1909 \pi }{65536},0,0,\frac{24955 \pi
   }{1048576},\frac{46923 \pi }{2097152},0,0,\frac{316301 \pi }{16777216},\frac{299973
   \pi }{16777216},0,0\right\}$$

Comment: Use the complex exponential representation of cosine. This reduces the integral to $2^n$ integrals on the form $\int_0^{2\pi}e^{iNx}dx$. This is only non-zero when $N=0$. From this we can see that the result will be $M 2\pi / 2^n$ for some integer $M$.  The number $N = a_1 + a_2 + \ldots + a_n$ where $a_k = \pm k$. For example for $n=3$ we have $2$ sums:  $1+2-3=0$ and $-1-2+3=0$ so the integral is $2\pi \cdot 2 / 2^3$.

Comment: @Winther so basically this becomes a combinatorial problem of finding how many ways there are to pick $n$ elements from $(-1,1),(-2,2),...,(-n,n)$ (one element per set), so that the sum of those $n$ elements is zero?

Comment: Yes thats exactly right. Or if you will: how many partitions there are of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ into two sets that have the same sum.

Comment: Use the Chebyshev polynomials of the first kind to expand $\cos(jx)$ perhaps?

Comment: btw you can find more info about that sequence here https://oeis.org/A063865 (it does not have a simple closed form, but its possible to find an asymptotic expression for it).

Comment: See also https://oeis.org/A058377

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint.** [From](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_integration#For_continuous_functions)
$$\int\limits_{\gamma}f(z)dz=\int\limits_{a}^{b}f(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)dt$$
with a transformation like
$$\int\limits_0^{2\pi} \prod_{j=1}^n \cos(jx)dx=
\int\limits_0^{2\pi} \prod_{j=1}^n \frac{e^{i j x}+e^{-i j x}}{2}dx=\\
\int\limits_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{2^n} \cdot\prod_{j=1}^n \frac{1}{e^{i j x}} \cdot \prod_{j=1}^n \left(e^{2i j x}+1\right)dx=\\
\int\limits_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{2^n} \cdot \frac{1}{e^{i \frac{n(n+1)}{2} x}} \cdot \prod_{j=1}^n \left(e^{2i j x}+1\right)dx=\\
\int\limits_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{i2^n} \cdot \frac{1}{e^{i \frac{n(n+1)}{2} x+ix}} \cdot \left(\prod_{j=1}^n \left(e^{2i j x}+1\right)\right) \cdot ie^{i x}dx=\\
\int\limits_{|z|=1}\frac{1}{i2^n} \cdot \frac{1}{z^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+1}} \cdot \prod_{j=1}^n \left(z^{2 j }+1\right)dz=...$$
and noting $f(z)=\prod\limits_{j=1}^n \left(z^{2 j }+1\right)$,
we have
$$...=\frac{1}{i2^n} \int\limits_{|z|=1}\frac{f(z)}{z^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+1}} dz=...$$
recalling [Cauchy's integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula#Theorem) this is
$$...=\frac{1}{i2^n}\cdot \frac{2 \pi i}{\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)!}\cdot f^{\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)}(0)=
\frac{\pi}{2^{n-1}} \cdot \frac{1}{\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)!} \cdot f^{\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)}(0)$$

Comment: I love seeing someone do the problem exactly as I would when I am too tired to do math. +1

Answer (score 3):

The integral is equal to $\frac{A_n\pi}{2^{n-1}}$ where $A_n$ is the number of subsets of   $\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}$ whose sum is $\frac{n(n+1)}4.$

In particular, if $n\equiv 1,2\pmod 4,$ the $\frac{n(n+1)}4$ is not an integer, so there can be no such aubsets, so the integral is zero in that case.

You get this value by representing $\cos nx =\frac12 \left(e^{inx}+e^{-inx}\right)$ and realize the integral is zero for all terms expanding the produc, except for the constant term, which has coefficient $\frac{A_n}{2^n}.$

I don’t think there is an easy way to represent this term. There is an upper bound $\binom n{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}.$

See this answer for details. [Compute $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \cos x \cos 2x\cdots \cos nx \space{dx}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170349/compute-lim-limits-n-to-infty-int-02-pi-cos-x-cos-2x-cdots-cos-nx)

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, the result is

$$ I_n = a_n \frac{2\pi}{2^{n}} $$

where $a_n$ is the numbers of solutions of $\sum_{j=1}^n s_n \,j =0$ where $s_j \in \{1,-1\}$ (or number of ways of marking a subset of $\{ 1,2, \cdots n\}$ such that the sum of the marked subset equals the sum of the unmarked subset). This is given by [OEIS A063865](https://oeis.org/A063865).

Asymptotics (for $n=0,3 \pmod 4$): $$I_n \approx \sqrt{24 \pi} \, n^{-3/2} $$

[Ref](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL16/Sullivan/sullivan8.pdf)